# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.example.drivie.Models.Comment

Tags: java, android

I want to retrive some data from database and display in a RecyclerView.

But when I run the app it throws me this:

> Process: com.example.****, PID: 22231
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.example.****.Models.Comment
>           at com.example.***.util.CommentAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CommentAdapter.java:39)
>           at com.example.****.util.CommentAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CommentAdapter.java:21) ....

I pass to the Adapter the same type of data I guess, I mean I do have an ArrayList and pass that. Let me show you.

This is the function in the Activity

```
private void initView() {
    RvComments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    db.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("email", email)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {

                             ArrayList<Comment> comments = (ArrayList<Comment>) document.get("comments");
                            commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(),comments );
                            RvComments.setAdapter(commentAdapter);


                        }
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

This is the adapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.CommentViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Comment> mData;

    public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Comment> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CommentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_comments, parent,false);
       return new CommentViewHolder(row);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).profilePicBy).into(holder.img_user);
        holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).postedBy);
        holder.tv_content.setText(mData.get(position).content);
        holder.tv_reply.setText(mData.get(position).reply);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  mData.size();
    }
    public class  CommentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView img_user;
        TextView tv_name,tv_content,tv_reply;
        Button reply;

        public CommentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img_user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_user_imd);
            tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_fullname);
            tv_content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_content);
            tv_reply = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_reply);
            reply = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_postReply);

            reply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("This button works");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Comment Class

```
public class Comment {
    public String postedBy;
    public String content;
    public String emailPostedBy;
    public String profilePicBy;
    public String reply;
    public String id;

    public Comment() {

    }

    public Comment(String postedby, String content, String emailPostedBy, String profilePicBy, String reply, String id){
        this.postedBy = postedby;
        this.content = content;
        this.emailPostedBy = emailPostedBy;
        this.profilePicBy = profilePicBy;
        this.reply = reply;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

In the public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList mData), I expect an ArrayList and in my function in the activity I pass the ArrayList, I don't know why I'm getting this, maybe you should know. Can you look over? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post the document text contining "comments" tag?  ArrayList<Comment> comments = (ArrayList<Comment>) document.get("comments");  It looks like it could be a serialization issue where you're not serializing the comment into a Comment object.  It looks like you're passing in a Map instead for your Comment.

Comment: Your logic also looks wrong regarding the for loop. You are replacing the adapter in every iteration when instead you should be adding existing comments to the current adapter. That is another issue I see.  You should store the comments and then set the adapter after all comments have been processed in the for loop.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much! I'll modify asap and let you know if it worked